# NetLogo - reading and writing to a text file for Java API use

Tags: java, netlogo

I want to use the Java API in my NetLogo program. For that,  I need to write to a text file and read input from a text file. How can this be done in NetLogo?

Additionally - what are the ways by which I can integrate the Java API with NetLogo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can read and write to a text file from NetLogo itself. There is no need to use the Java API. Read about the file commands in the manual found here: http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/5.0/docs/programming.html#fileio